# c#, import class file to main program file

Tags: c#, class

I have started with c# and having problems to import a class file to my main file.
At this point i cant figure out why it is not working.

Here is the file directory.

[image: file directory]

and here is the main program.

[image: main program]

and here is the other class i want to import called Player.
[image]

When i,m trying to use the dot notation. currentPlayer.name it does not recognise it. What is the problem here?

Comment: What's the error? What line is it on? What suggestions does your IDE make?

Comment: It has no problem seeing your class. It has a problem seeing the variables that you're trying to access, because those variables are local variables created in the constructor, and not stored as public properties or fields of the class itself. This is covered in basic C# tutorials: you should start by going through some of those so that you don't get tripped up on basic language concepts like this one.

Comment: the error is: Error CS1061: 'Player' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (TextRpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Answer (score 1):

If your class looked like:

```
public class Player{

  //this is a publicly visible property called Name
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public Player(){
    //this is a constructor method
  }


}
```

Then it would work as you expect (though you'd need to say `currentPlayer.Name`, not `name` - C# is case sensitive):

```
static void Main(){

  var p = new Player();
  p.Name = "Steve";
}
```

Please observe C# naming guidelines when coding - **P**ublicThingsArePascalCase

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access variables declared in the Player constructor from outside the scope of that class. The variables declared inside the constructor can only be accessed in the scope of that constructor.

I understand you want to access all those local variables like currentHealth or maxHealth from outisde the class, as attributes of Player. Move them outside the constructor scope (outside of Player() { ... } ) and declare each of them as a property with a getter/setter (see example below).

If you want to access for instance Player.Name, I suggest you declare the Player class as follows:

```
public class Player
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, inside Program.cs's Main method you can call it as follows:

```
var currentPlayer = new Player();    
currentPlayer.Name = "Some name";
```

Comment: How come i cant write 
public int health = 100;
in the Player class file and find it with the dot notation in the program class?

Comment: @Joakim Because you're failing to take into account the scope of the variable. Just like I told you in the comments on the question, you need to go through some C#  tutorials, such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/) in order to understand basics of the language.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write like this to get the variables from Player class. Following code is from class Program.

```
namespace TextRpg
{
class Program
{
    public static Player currentPlayer = new Player();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        currentPlayer.name = Console.ReadLine();
        Start();    
    }

    static void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A GAME");
        Console.WriteLine("Name: ");
            
    }
}
```

and from the Player class.

```
class Player
{

    public string name = "";

        public int currentHealth = 100;
        public int maxHealth = 100;

        int inventorySpace = 5;
        int maxInventorySpace = 5;

        int carryWeapons = 2;
        int maxCarryWeapons = 2;

        int armorValue = 0;
        int maxArmorValue = 10;

}
```

Now i can access every variable (string and int) through the dot notation from Player class to Program class.

I need to change the int to public otherwise i cant find them in the program class.

Answer (score -1):

use public property such as:

```
public string name {get; set;}
```

Comment: Simply making it public isn't enough, the declaration of those variables has to be moved to a field or property rather than a local variable.